# REST: returning list of objects as a CSV without writing on disk (java spring)

Tags: java, spring, rest, csv

I have following class. and I am getting list of objects of this class through JPA repository query.

```
public class SettlementSummaryDTO {
   private Long id;
   private String filePath;
   private Double commissionAmount;
   private String merchantGroupId;
   private Double netTransactionAmount;
   private Double purchaseAmount;
   private Long purchaseCount;
   private Double refundAmount;
   private Long refundCount;
   private Double settlemantAmount;
   private Integer settlementBatchNumber;
   private Double taxAmount;
   private Date date;
   private String merchantId;
   private String merchantName;
   private String location;
   private SettlementStatus settlementStatus;
}
```

So I have List SettlementSummaryDTOs. I want to convert this list of object to CSV(Each object in list as a single row). And I want to return this CSV as a file to client(browser). But I don't want to write it on disk. How this can be achieved ?

Note: I tried following but couldn't get success(Getting empty file in response)

```
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
CsvWriterSettings csvWriterSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();
csvWriterSettings.setAutoConfigurationEnabled(true);
CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(servletOutputStream, csvWriterSettings);
csvWriter.addValues(settlementSummaryDTOs);
httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/csv");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=settlement.csv");
csvWriter.flush();
```

Comment: "I tried following but couldn't get success"? Because?

Comment: I am getting empty file.

Comment: And if you write it to a `FileOutputStream` it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using univocity-parsers. You will have to annotate the fields or methods of your `SettlementSummaryDTO` class with `@Parsed`.

Then you can write your beans to the output with this one-liner:

```
new CsvRoutines().
    writeAll(settlementSummaryDTOs, SettlementSummaryDTO.class, servletOutputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Worked with new CsvRoutines().
    writeAll(settlementSummaryDTOs, SettlementSummaryDTO.class, servletOutputStream); Removed last argument. When last argument was there it was giving only "UTF-8" in response. may be it was considering it header. Anyways my problem is solved but just want to understand why didn't worked with last argument.

Comment: My bad, you should use `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` instead of just "UTF-8". The method signature takes a sequence of alternative headers if you want to have a custom header row.

Comment: Works like charm.

Comment: Is it possible if I want to run the loop and inside loop I will get new list settlementSummaryDTOs everytime and call CsvRoutines().writeAll() everytime in loop ? I am getting settlementSummaryDTOs from database and planning to fetch 500 records once. So If there are 1500 records in database I will get settlementSummaryDTOs 3 times and I will call CsvRoutines().writeAll() thrice.

Comment: You can use a `CsvWriter` instead. Just pass a `BeanWriterProcessor` to the `CsvWriterSettings` and from your writer call `processRecord(yourBean)` or `processRecord(yourListOfBeans)`. It's a bit more of code but not much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using PrintWriter? I have below code which works fine

httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/csv");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.csv");

```
    try {
        List<String[]> allLines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        allLines.add(new String[]{"Doc1", "10000", "1", "Personal"});
        allLines.add(new String[]{"Doc2", "20000", "2", "Commercial"});

        PrintWriter printWriter = httpServletResponse.getWriter(); ---> Use Print Writer

        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(printWriter);
        csvWriter.writeAll(allLines);

        csvWriter.flush();
        csvWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Here I will need to convert List<SettlementSummaryDTO> to List<String[]> which I don't want to do.

Comment: This is one of the implementation, important thing to take away from here is you have to use `PrintWriter printWriter = httpServletResponse.getWriter(); ` and which ever csv api you are using, you should pass printwriter in writer instance parameter.